# Issue with text shown in modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have created a simple modal with HTML/CSS and Javascript. Modal is working the way I want it to work. The only issue I have is that the last word in the text that I want to display is always displayed in a new line.
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

```js
function revealModal(divID) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
  };
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
}

function hideModal(divID) {
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none";
}

function showOKPopUp(message) {
  var confirmText = '<div class="modalBody">' +
    '<table width="100%" border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">' +
    '<tr> <td bgcolor="#D6E3F7"><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >' +
    '<tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" ><label><br />' +
    message +
    '</label></td>' +
    '</tr><tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>' +
    '<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '<span class="text-b" style="padding:5px"> <br />' +
    '<input name="Submit32" onclick="hideModal(\'modalPage\')"  type="button" class="b_st" value="OK" />' +
    '<br /><br /></span></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>';

  document.getElementById('modalPage').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML = confirmText;
  revealModal('modalPage');
}
```

```css
.text-b {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
}

.b_st {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #5585CC;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
  opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

#popup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 25%;
}

#modalPage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalBackground {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=40);
  -moz-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 750;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 4px black;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.modalTop {
  width: 292px;
  background-color: #000099;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
}

.modalTop a,
.modalTop a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modalBody {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalPage">
  <div class="modalBackground"></div>
  <div class="modalContainer"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="showOKPopUp('Hello There!!')">Show Modal</button>
```

I can not figure out why it is. May be I am missing something.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: Why do you have two tables in you modal? Have you tried increasing the width of your modalBody class?

Comment: The problem is the last word of the text always comes in a new line. I can not understand why? @Bhargav

Comment: Width of modal adjusts automatically based on the text length as you can see from the two attached images. I guess the issue of last word is due to something else. @MehravishTemkar

Comment: That you are using tables here might as well have something to do with it, because tables have their own layout algorithm. Nothing of what you have shown so far justifies the use of a table here IMHO. And the `br` element is not a “spacing” tool either. You should go read up on some basics of specifying such layout/formatting things with CSS instead.

Comment: Setting the second table's width to 95% seems to be causing the problem. You could really work it out without using two tables. Just one is enough

Comment: IMO, this is also a semantically incorrect use of `<label>`. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) explains, "The HTML `<label>` element represents a caption **for an item in a user interface.**". It is meant to be linked to a form element, for making things like the text next to a checkbox activate the checkbox; not as a general text holder. If you need to wrap your text in something, I'd just use a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the paragraph in one line you have to use `white-space: nowrap;` for `label`, check the updated snippet.

```js
function revealModal(divID) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
  };
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
}

function hideModal(divID) {
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none";
}

function showOKPopUp(message) {
  var confirmText = '<div class="modalBody">' +
    '<table width="100%" border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">' +
    '<tr> <td bgcolor="#D6E3F7"><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >' +
    '<tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" ><label><br />' +
    message +
    '</label></td>' +
    '</tr><tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>' +
    '<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '<span class="text-b" style="padding:5px"> <br />' +
    '<input name="Submit32" onclick="hideModal(\'modalPage\')"  type="button" class="b_st" value="OK" />' +
    '<br /><br /></span></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>';

  document.getElementById('modalPage').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML = confirmText;
  revealModal('modalPage');
}
```

```css
.text-b {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
}

.b_st {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #5585CC;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
  opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

#popup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 25%;
}

#modalPage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalBackground {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=40);
  -moz-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 750;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 4px black;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.modalTop {
  width: 292px;
  background-color: #000099;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
}

.modalTop a,
.modalTop a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modalBody {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
max-width: 100%;
min-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalPage">
  <div class="modalBackground"></div>
  <div class="modalContainer"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="showOKPopUp('Hello There!!')">Show Modal</button>
```

**Update**

I have removed `white-space: nowrap;` and added `min-width` and `max-width` for `.modalBody` , check the snippet again.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This works. But I am actually looking for reason why the last word is coming in a new line, so that I can handle it in more flexible way. Means, when the message is long, I want it to wrap. But the message is short I'll prefer no-wrap.

Answer (score 0):

set

```
label{
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

so it will work

```js
function revealModal(divID) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
  };
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
}

function hideModal(divID) {
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none";
}

function showOKPopUp(message) {
  var confirmText = '<div class="modalBody">' +
    '<table width="100%" border="5" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">' +
    '<tr> <td bgcolor="#D6E3F7"><table width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" >' +
    '<tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" ><label><br />' +
    message +
    '</label></td>' +
    '</tr><tr><td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>' +
    '<td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D6E3F7" style="padding:5px" class="text-b" >' +
    '<span class="text-b" style="padding:5px"> <br />' +
    '<input name="Submit32" onclick="hideModal(\'modalPage\')"  type="button" class="b_st" value="OK" />' +
    '<br /><br /></span></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>';
  document.getElementById('modalPage').getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML = confirmText;
  revealModal('modalPage');

}
```

```css
.text-b {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
}

.b_st {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #5585CC;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#mask {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.75;
  opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

#popup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 25%;
}

#modalPage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalBackground {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=40);
  -moz-opacity: 0.4;
  opacity: 0.4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 500;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.modalContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 750;
}

.modal {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 4px black;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.modalTop {
  width: 292px;
  background-color: #000099;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: right;
}

.modalTop a,
.modalTop a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.modalBody {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -150px;
}

label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="modalPage">
  <div class="modalBackground"></div>
  <div class="modalContainer"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="showOKPopUp('Hello There!!')">Show Modal</button>
```

Comment: This definitely works but this is not what I am looking for. I don't want a no-wrap always. If I could find the reason why it is wrapping the last word in a newline, I could use it in a more flexible way. Means I would like to wrap the message when it is too long.

Comment: so you can define width of that label